# payment gateway (payzippy) integration with rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello guys am working on an rails app, and is want to integrate payzippy payment gateway with rails app, but is am unable to figure it out that how to do this, any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Get a sand box account from payzippy and use this app https://github.com/payzippy/rails-sdk-payzippy.git . just replace the config credentials its works for me..